# Using Two-Dimensional Array to retrieve file information

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, file, multidimensional-array

Is it possible to use 2-Dimensional arrays to capture a file's name and its base64 content (assuming it was converted beforehand)? How would one go about doing this?

I would assume that this would include using two ngModels as:

In **app.component.html**

```
[(ngModel)]="userModel.fileDocs[0][0]" [(ngModel)]="userModel.fileDocs[0][1]"
```

The first binding and second bindings respectively capturing the names and content.

- The first file's name which is at [0][0], and the file's content [0][1].
- The second file's name at [1][0] and its content at [1][1].
- The third file's name at [2][0] and its content at [2][1].
- The fourth file's name at [3][0] and its content at [3][1].

In **app.component.ts**

```
[['', ''], ['', ''], ['', ''], ['','']]
```

The first through fourth arrays within the array would be the first index in the [0-3][] array. The strings within the array would be accessed through the second index of the 2-D array, [][0-1].

I was trying to make an iteration that adds the file name and content to the array strings however the result is that only the array within the 2-D array was iterated.

In **app.component.ts**

```
   for (let i = 0; i < modifiedUserModel.fileDocs.length; i++) {
    // Update file values from userModel to include the base64 string content and the file name
      modifiedUserModel.fileDocs[i][0] =  '{"fileName": "' +  this.elem.files[i].name + '"';
      modifiedUserModel.fileDocs[i][1] =  '"fileData": "' + this.base64result + '"}';
    }
```

The expected result was the the file names would align with the first string in each of the arrays in the 2-D array, and that the base64 would be entered into the second string of the arrays in the 2-D array content.

```
 "fileDocs": [
    [
      "{\"fileName\": \"output1.docx\"",
      "\"fileData\": \"base64 content Here\"}"
    ],
    [
      "{\"fileName\": \"output2.docx\"",
      "\"fileData\": \"base64 content Here\"}"
    ],
    [
      "{\"fileName\": \"output3.docx\"",
      "\"fileData\": \"base64 content Here\"}"
    ],
    [
      "{\"fileName\": \"output4.docx\"",
      "\"fileData\": \"base64 content Here\"}"
    ]
  ]
```

The actual result that this only occurred for the first array in the 2-D array. The others only displayed the filepath of the file, on both the name and content string area. Also, the last submitted file ended up being the one that goes through as the first file. I assume this one's to do with the iteration.

```
 "fileDocs": [
    [
      "{\"fileName\": \"output4.docx\"",
      "\"fileData\": \"base64 content Here\"}"
    ],
    [
      "C:\\fakepath\\output2.docx",
      "C:\\fakepath\\output2.docx"
    ],
    [
      "C:\\fakepath\\output3.docx",
      "C:\\fakepath\\output3.docx"
    ],
    [
      "C:\\fakepath\\output4.docx",
      "C:\\fakepath\\output4.docx"
    ]
  ]
```

Comment: Of course it's possible, the question is why would you? Just have an array of objects with `name` and `data` properties...

Comment: Yeah, this seems to be the correct approach, what you've suggested. Current issue is that the fileName and fileData properties capture the latest value of the file and repeats it for other entries I uploaded, but they, as object properties are functioning as intended. Likely something to do with that for loop. Thanks for your help.